# iPhone Tablview cell - corner triangle

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Has anyone seen a snippet (or class/library) that will draw that corner triangle in a tableview cell (see below image).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new view from an image and then add it to the cell calling addSubview. Here is a example setting the corner upon launch:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        CGRect cornerFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
        UIImageView * corner = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cornerFrame];
        [corner setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner.jpg"]];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:corner];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This won't work properly...cells get reused, you'll be adding many of these to each cell if you implement it in this way.

Comment: This is juts en example of calling `addSubview`. He may use it wherever he wants.

Comment: In this particular spot it'll break though :) The only thing worse than no code sample, is a bad code sample.

Comment: Really? Because I have implementations looking like that and they work. Maybe I was wrong all the time. I should probably pick other cell identifiers.

Comment: Changed the source, fixed now? =)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably just an image in the cell. Nothing too fancy, just your standard run of the mill custom `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

it's built in `UITableViewCell`... **Simple** ..

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
```

[image]